# Why doesn't my Tkinter button do something?

Tags: python, tkinter

so i made a button on my tkinter-field,witch would return an entry in an field,witch I built prior,thanks for that,anyway it doesn' return anything,here is a snippet of my source code

```
entry = Entry()
entry.pack()
def get_entry():
    entry.get()
schaltf2 = tkinter.Button(root, text="submit", width=20, command=get_entry())
schaltf2.pack(side="bottom")
```

could maybe anyone help me,that would be very nice,thank you!:)

Comment: You assign the result of a call to "get_entry" to "command" argument. Remove the parentheses to assign the function itself.

Comment: *" it doesn' return anything"* because the function does not have a `return` statement.  Even it returns something, it is discarded if it is called by a button click callback.

Answer (score 0):

this is because first you have to do a `StringVar()` object to get the value, so to initialize the entry you have to do:

```
string_var = tkinter.StringVar(root)
entry = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable=string_var)
```

and in the function `get_entry()` you have to return `entry.get()`
so you would do:

```
>>> def get_entry():
...    return entry.get()
```